# Dynamic Type with Mappings

Tags: elasticsearch

My data is structure is very generic. and almost any type of data fits in my datastructure.

```
Document{
    "id" : 12345678,
    "fields" : 
        [{
            "name" : "Book title",
            "value" : "Harry Potter",
            "type" : "string"
        },
        {
            "name" : "price",
            "value" : 34.50,
            "type" : "float"
        }]
}
```

Another Document could be like this:

```
Document{
    "id" : 123456790,
    "fields" : 
        [{
            "name" : "Blog title",
            "value" : "My awesome blog",
            "type" : "string"
        }]
}
```

This data can change and fields could have any type and names.
How can I dynamically create a template mapping so that the "type" for mapping is set by the value of the "type" in my data?
e.g. value: 34.50, type: float
at the same time the same data "value" : "Harry Potter", type : string

I have seen that is has been done in ES but I can't get my head around making a mapping that actually uses the value of "type" specified in the document to actually set the correct type for the value.

Specifying types is particularly useful for me in a sense I can have for example, location type, date type, integer or ... on the same data structure.

I have been trying to find any content either online or in books but so far nothing.
Is this even possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you'll want to use [nested](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-nested-type.html) types to make sure a query/filter on name is not mingled with values of another field of the same document.

Secondly, you cannot have different types with the same field name, in this case "value". Thus, you will need to change the structure of the doucments you send to Elasticsearch a bit.

When you say "any type", will you have control on the number of types? If you do, you can do things like having fields called "date_value", "location_value", "float_value" (or something similar) and so on. "string_value" is not really a good one. What analyzer will it have? It might be better to have a type named for its purpose, e.g. "keyword_value" (for things you might want to facet on, for example), "name_value" (which can have fuzzy support), "text_value" (analyzed for proper search), and so on.

I made a runnable example you can play with here: https://www.found.no/play/gist/7596633

Comment: Hi Alex, Thanks for your effort. In my example I forgot to enclose objects to an array. In case of an array would it still be the same? e.g. Document { fields [ {field}, {field} ] }

Comment: I just realized you did use an array :) I am checking it