# mapping for objects with an arbitrary amount of properties in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

i have a given document:

```
{
  "foo": {}
}
```

where `foo` can have an arbitrary amount of properties. lets assume i will import millions of documents into my index, in which each of `foo`'s properties do have other values.

that means my mapping which will be built dynamically will grow enormous. is there any kind of way where i can tell elasticsearch something like

> take everything you have in `foo` and just accept it as it is (or stringify `foo`) without having a resulting million-lines-mapping???

or do i have to care by myself, before indexing documents?

if so, there a 2 solutions i think

1. `JSON.stringify` `foo`
2. map every property in `foo` into key/value pairs, and create an array of objects:

   ```
   // object
   {
     "foo": [
       {"key": "bar1", "value": "bar1's value"},
       {"key": "bar2", "value": "bar2's value"}
     ]
   }

   // resulting mapping
   {
     "type": {
       "properties": {
         "foo": {
           "properties": {
             "key": {
               "type": "string" 
             },
             "value": {
               "type": "string" 
             }
           }
         }
       }
     }   
   }
   ```

would you prefer then solution 1 or 2, and why?

appreciate your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot make Elasticsearch stringify it for you. You can make it ignore whatever's under "foo" and it'll be a part of "_source", but then it will not be searchable at all.

The second approach can make a lot of sense, depending on how you're going to query it, and what you can know about the kinds of values you will accept.

There is a related question at [Dynamic Type with Mappings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20138641/dynamic-type-with-mappings) describing this approach, with a runnable example here: https://www.found.no/play/gist/7596633

The idea is that you'll have a nested document per value. This works well if the number of values per document is not huge. If you don't use nested documents, your document would be returned if you search for "key": "bar1" and "value": "bar2's value".

Comment: thanks for your answer. how do i ignore it? if i do this, i can not search on that field, but it will still be part of the document when i retrieve this right?

Comment: found it: {"enabled": "false", "type": "object"}, anyways, thanks a lot for your help!